# opengl fragment shader conditional statement not triggered

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I am going through the tutorial at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut03%20More%20Power%20To%20The%20Shaders.html

I am currently on a lesson which creates a triangle, moves it in a circular direction and gradually change the color from white to green.  The color will jump back to white after a complete cycle.  I am trying to make the color move gradually from white to green and back.
My conditional statement to set my color change direction appears to never evaluate to true so my change never takes effect.

Here is my fragment shader.

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform float fragLoopDuration; //5.0f
uniform float time;


const vec4 firstColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
const vec4 secondColor = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

void main()
{
    bool myFlag = false; //flag will indicate which direction color change will take.
    float currTime = mod(time, fragLoopDuration);
    float currLerp = currTime / fragLoopDuration; //currLerp range = (0.0f-1.0f)
    if (currLerp == 0.9f) myFlag = !myFlag; //this flag is not geting triggered.
    if (myFlag) outputColor = mix(secondColor, firstColor, currLerp * -1.0f + 1.0f); //green to white
    if (!myFlag) outputColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, currLerp); //white to green
}
```

Comment: Sorry, problem is my conditional statement to set my flag appears to never evaluate to true.  Thus my desired change to the color never occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry, problem is my conditional statement to set my flag appears to never evaluate to true.

What do you expect? In order for `currLerp` to be *exactly* equal to 0.9f, `currTime` and `fragLoopDuration` must be very specific and very *exact* values. If `currTime` is even slightly off, by even 0.000001, then `currLerp` won't be exactly equal to 0.9f, and thus your condition will never be true.

In general, you should never test a float for *equality*. That is, equal to another value.

And even if it is exactly equal, it will only ever happen *once*. So it will be true on exactly one frame; the next frame, when `currLerp` is 0.95f or something, it will be false again.

I'm guessing you mean `>=` rather than `==`.

---

As an aside, your code is not structured the way most programmers would do it.

You have this flag that you set. Then you have two `if` statements, one that will be executed if the flag is true, and one that will be executed if the flag is false. This is a waste and poor coding style. Pretty much every language with `if` will also have some form of `else`: the thing that happens if the condition is not true.

The standard way to do this is here:

```
if (myFlag)
  outputColor = mix(secondColor, firstColor, currLerp * -1.0f + 1.0f);
else
  outputColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, currLerp);
```

And since you only use `myFlag` once, there's no point in even having a variable:

```
if (currLerp == 0.9f) //Fix this, of course
  outputColor = mix(secondColor, firstColor, currLerp * -1.0f + 1.0f);
else
  outputColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, currLerp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the style critique.  Perhaps you could also comment on how to achieve my desired effect?

Comment: @Paul: If I was going to just give you the answer, [I wouldn't have assigned it as Further Study](http://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) ;)

Comment: if (currLerp < 0.5f) outputColor = mix(secondColor, firstColor, currLerp);
else outputColor = mix(firstColor, secondColor, currLerp);
This brings about a smooth transition, however the color intensity for green suffers due to never reaching a full currLerp value.  Does this satisfy the requirements or was there some other solution you had in mind?